# How to run a minecraft server without port forwarding?

Tags: 13.04, minecraft

I have been looking for a while and cant seem to find out how to run a minecraft server on linux without forwarding my ports. I can forward my ports because it is blocked in my router and I would really like to run a minecraft server. Any help would be appreciated, thanks! Don’t be afraid to ask for extra info!

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited at [gaming.se]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Hamachi for Linux (It is command line not GUI) Hamachi is a VPN but other users will need Hamachi in order to access your Minecraft server.

Download:

https://secure.logmein.com/labs/#HamachiforLinux (Press on "Learn More" to reveal download links)

Here's a video tutorial for the setup:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8OQA4HXhk4

Comment: Thanks, its not exactly what I'm looking for. I used it in windows and cant seem to get the word about the server out. I can use it. Its just not my first choice. Not a big deal I guess. I can just use it for a private server. On top of that we are about to switch internet providers so port forwarding can wait until then. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to have a server accessible from outside your private network without port forwarding. Another name for it is Port Address Translation (PAT).
Any router is capable of doing NAT/PAT, it's one of the basic core functions that make it a router.

The purpose of a router is to route traffic from one network to another.
If correctly configured it will not "block" traffic.

However many (most?) el cheepo modems/routers provided by ISP's have a rudimentary embedded firewall. The firewall is more likely the part that is blocking traffic.
You will have to configure the firewall to allow access from the internet on a given port #.

This port# is the port# that clients use to connect to your server.
The router may be configured to forward (NAT/PAT) traffic from the internet arriving on that port number to another port on your server.
This does not have to be the exact same port number, depending on the router's quality it may even be impossible to forward using the exact same port number that you've opened up on the outside.

Also, Please note that most people are unaware of the fact that their (modern) (server) operating system also has a so called software firewall active.
By default it may be configured to block all incoming traffic from the internet.
You will need to allow traffic to come from the internet on the published IP/Port number